# create file index manually using powershell, tab delimited

Tags: powershell, windows-10

Sorry in advance for the probably trivial question, I'm a powershell noob, please bear with me and give me advice on how to get better.

I want to achieve a file index `index.txt` that contains the list of all files in current dir and subdirs in this format:

```
./dir1/file1.txt   07.05.2020 16:16   1959281
```

where

1. dirs listed are relative (i.e. this will be run remotely and to save space, the relative path is good enough)
2. the delimiter is a tab `\t`
3. the date format is `day.month.fullyear hours:minutes:seconds`, last written (this is the case for me, but I'm guessing this would be different on system setting and should be enforced)
4. (the last number is the size in bytes)

I almost get there using this command in powershell (maybe that's useful to someone else as well):

```
 get-childitem . -recurse  | select fullname,LastWriteTime,Length | Out-File index.txt
```

with this result

```
FullName                                     LastWriteTime       Length
--------                                     -------------       ------
C:\Users\user1\Downloads\test\asdf.txt       07.05.2020 16:19:29   1490
C:\Users\user1\Downloads\test\dirtree.txt    07.05.2020 16:08:44      0
C:\Users\user1\Downloads\test\index.txt      07.05.2020 16:29:01      0
C:\Users\user1\Downloads\test\test.txt       07.05.2020 16:01:23    814
C:\Users\user1\Downloads\test\text2.txt      07.05.2020 15:55:45   1346
```

So the questions that remain are: How to...

1. get rid of the headers?
2. enforce this date format?
3. tab delimit everything?
4. get control of what newline character is used (`\n` or `\r` or both)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the path you are running this from is NOT the current scrip path, do:

```
$path = 'D:\Downloads' # 'X:\SomeFolder\SomeWhere'
Set-Location $path
```

first.

Next, this ought to do it:

```
Get-ChildItem . -Recurse -File  | ForEach-Object {
    "{0}`t{1:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm}`t{2}" -f ($_ | Resolve-Path -Relative), $_.LastWriteTime, $_.Length
} | Out-File 'index.txt'
```

On Windows the newline will be `\r\n` (CRLF)

If you want control over that, this should do:

```
$newline = "`n"   # for example
# capture the lines as string array in variable $lines
$lines = Get-ChildItem . -Recurse -File  | ForEach-Object {
    "{0}`t{1:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm}`t{2}" -f ($_ | Resolve-Path -Relative), $_.LastWriteTime, $_.Length
}
# join the array with the chosen newline and save to file
$lines -join $newline | Out-File 'index.txt' -NoNewline
```

<sup>Because your requirement is to NOT have column headers in the output file, I'm using `Out-File` here instead of `Export-Csv`</sup>

Comment: can the newline \n be written just with one line of code, like the first code snippet? It may be a bit cheeky to ask, but it would be super helpful if you could elaborate on some of the commands, e.g. the for-each one. Other than that, this works flawlessly, that's impressive!

Comment: @user2305193 you _CAN_ cram it all into a single line, but i would strongly advise against it. It would make the code barely readable and difficult to maintain. See for yourself: `$newline = "`n"; $lines $lines = Get-ChildItem . -Recurse -File |ForEach-Object { "{0}`t{1:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm}`t{2}" -f ($_ | Resolve-Path -Relative), $_.LastWriteTime, $_.Length }; $lines -join $newline | Out-File 'index.txt' -NoNewline`

Comment: @user2305193. `ForEach-Object` iterates a collection of things, one thing at a time. Inside that loop, the `$_` variable represents the current thing. In this case each thing is a FileInfo object as returned from the `Get_ChildItem` cmdlet.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach could be this:

```
$StartDirectory = Get-Location
Get-ChildItem -Path $StartDirectory -recurse | 
    Select-Object -Property @{Name='RelPath';Expression={$_.FullName.toString() -replace [REGEX]::Escape($StartDirectory.ToString()),'.'}},
                            @{Name='LastWriteTime';Expression={$_.LastWriteTime.toString('dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss')}},
                            Length | 
                                Export-Csv -Path Result.csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "`t"
```

I recommend to use proper CSV files if you have structured data like this. The resulting CSV file will be saved in the current working directory.

Comment: thanks for the recommend, I guess more space is saved with csv as compared to tabs (2 chars vs 1)

Comment: @user2305193 I don't get, sorry. What do you mean with that? And regardless of that - is it really that important to save (that little) space to even spend more effort and loose some information?

Comment: csv stands for comma delimited values, which I presumed you suggested because it's more efficient than tab delimited values (I guess tsv?)

Comment: Ah ... no. Despite the name implies that you use commas as delimiter you can actually specify the delimiter with the parameter `-Delimiter` what I did in the code. A comma charachter takes the same "space" like a space charachter or a semicolon. That does not matter in this case. I think it depends what you plan to do with the data you just created. If you want to use them in further steps with Powershell it does not matter and you could just stick with the default - the comma.